# I need to write SQL against a star schema where I have products with supplier in one city and consumer in another and vice versa

Tags: sql-server

I have a star schema with transactions as fact table.

For each product list the quantity sold by suppliers in Madison to consumers in Chicago versus the quantity sold by suppliers in Chicago to consumers in Madison (result columns: product name, quantity Madison_Chicago, quantity Chicago_Madison)

I have tried intersect and union all

```
SELECT 
    P.Name as Product
   , SUM(T.Quantity) as QMad
   , dbo.Tb_Consumer C
   , dbo.Tb_Supplier S
   , dbo.Tb_Transactions T
   where P.Prod_ID = T.Prod_ID
   and C.Con_ID = T.Con_ID
   and S.Supp_ID = T.Supp_ID
   and S.City = 'Madison'
   and C.City = 'Chicago'
  from dbo.Tb_Product P
  group by P.Name
  union all
  SELECT P.Name as Product
  , sum(T.Quantity) as QCHI
  from dbo.Tb_Product P
  , dbo.Tb_Consumer C
  ,dbo.Tb_Supplier S
  ,dbo.Tb_Transactions T
  where P.Prod_ID = T.Prod_ID
  and C.Con_ID = T.Con_ID
  and S.Supp_ID = T.Supp_ID
  and S.City = 'Chicago'
  and C.City = 'Madison'
  group by P.Name
```

Expecting the following

```
Product   chi_qy   Mad_qy
-------------------------
Auto       3        2
```

but I get

```
Product   chi_qy    
----------------- 
Auto       3        
Auto       2
```

Comment: Please write SQL with proper Joins (inner join left join etc) ..  this union won't work as you have more columns in the top than in the second select.. please show data and schema of your tables so we can see what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Please stop with the [old style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just join two query instead of union 
like this :

```
select X.Product,QMad,QCHI
from(
SELECT 
    P.Name as Product
   , SUM(T.Quantity) as QMad
   from dbo.Tb_Product P
   , dbo.Tb_Consumer C
   , dbo.Tb_Supplier S
   , dbo.Tb_Transactions T
   where P.Prod_ID = T.Prod_ID
   and C.Con_ID = T.Con_ID
   and S.Supp_ID = T.Supp_ID
   and S.City = 'Madison'
   and C.City = 'Chicago'
  from dbo.Tb_Product P
  group by P.Name) X
inner join
  (SELECT P.Name as Product
  , sum(T.Quantity) as QCHI
  from dbo.Tb_Product P
  , dbo.Tb_Consumer C
  ,dbo.Tb_Supplier S
  ,dbo.Tb_Transactions T
  where P.Prod_ID = T.Prod_ID
  and C.Con_ID = T.Con_ID
  and S.Supp_ID = T.Supp_ID
  and S.City = 'Chicago'
  and C.City = 'Madison'
  group by P.Name) Y on X.Product=Y.Product
```

and if it could be blank in each side , you can use left , right or full outer join